# cmake custom command to copy and rename

Tags: command, cmake

I have an existing cmake file that generates a .so library. I want to modify it so that it will then make a copy of the .so named something else. This is roughly what I have:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.7)
PROJECT(test1)

SET(TEST_SOURCES f1.c)
ADD_LIBRARY(test SHARED ${TEST_SOURCES})
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
    OUTPUT custom1
    COMMAND cp libtest.so custom1
    DEPENDS libtest.so)
```

I realise there are better ways than hardcoding the library name, I'm just doing this while I try and figure out how to make it work at all.
What's the thing I'm missing that will cause my copy/rename custom command to run?
Note: this is not an install-time thing.
Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
add_custom_target(CopyAndRename
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test.so ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/SomeThingElse.so
)
```

add_custom_target introduces a new target named CopyAndRename. You can run it with:

```
cmake CopyAndRename
```

Answer (score 26):

I'd stick with your original idea of using [`add_custom_command`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_command).  However, I'd recommend you use the `add_custom_command(TARGET ...)` form rather than `add_custom_command(OUTPUT ...)`.

The `OUTPUT` version is designed to have the output file used as a source file in a different CMake target in the same CMakeLists.txt.  The custom command is invoked when this target is built (right at the start), since the target needs the file to exist at that point.

In your case, no target depends on your file - it's a product of the build process.

If you use `add_custom_command(TARGET ...)`, this guarantees the command is executed every time the target is rebuilt.  Using `add_custom_target` requires you to remember to build this if the original target (`test` in this case) is updated.  It also needlessly adds to your list of targets - maybe not an issue for a tiny project, but it can be for larger projects.

Here's how I'd set up the command:

```
SET(COPY_TO_PATH custom1)
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(TARGET test POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                       $<TARGET_FILE:test>
                       ${COPY_TO_PATH}
                   COMMENT "Copying 'test' library to '${COPY_TO_PATH}'")
```

This adds the command as a post-build event of `test`'s.  As you rightly identified, hard-coding library names isn't great; hence CMake provides "generator expressions" to handle this.  The generator expression `$<TARGET_FILE:test>` resolves to the full path of the library created by `test`, regardless of platform or compiler.  Note that generator expressions can only be used in the `COMMAND` argument; you couldn't use them in the `COMMENT` part for example.

The actual command is invoking CMake itself (`${CMAKE_COMMAND}`) with its [`-E` command line option](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#opt%3a-E).  This provides a cross-platform way to achieve the copy, since `cp` isn't a Windows command.  To see all `-E` options, run `cmake -E help`.

Answer (score 10):

You may consider using `configure_file`

```
configure_file("path-to-your-so-file.so" "new-path-to-your-so-file.so" COPYONLY)
```

Comment: Take notice that this command also creates a link between source and destination file and, in the futue, if the source file is modified copying will be redone. This might be wanted, or might not.

Comment: @DinoSaric may u provide a link for your information? I do not think configure_file just create a link between source and dest file. It copies source file to dest. And I think this is the simplest way to copy file with CMAKE.

Comment: Yes, it will copy, but if the input file is modified in the future, CMake will reconfigure and copy the file to the output. 

From [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html): 
If the input file is modified the build system will re-run CMake to re-configure the file and generate the build system again. The generated file is modified and its timestamp updated on subsequent cmake runs only if its content is changed.