# CMake custom command to generate a non-config file

Tags: cmake, cmake-custom-command

I've read:

[cmake custom command to copy and rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590445/cmake-custom-command-to-copy-and-rename)

and I want to do something similar, but rather than copying a file, I want to generate a file. If that wasn't in a custom command, I would write:

```
file(WRITE "generated.c" "int main() { return 0; }")
```

but it doesn't seem like `cmake -E` supports this directly. What should I do (other than run something platform-dependent)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CMake's script mode (`-P`). In `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(test)

file(
  GENERATE
  OUTPUT "gen.cmake"
  CONTENT [[
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
file(WRITE "${OUT}" "int main() { return 0; }")
]])

add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT generated.c
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DOUT=generated.c 
          -P gen.cmake
  DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gen.cmake"
)

add_executable(main "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated.c")
```

Note that if the file you generate has configuration-dependent contents, then you must include `$<CONFIG>` somewhere in the file name. See the docs here for more detail: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#generate

Comment: And can't I inline my script somehow?

Comment: @einpoklum - edited... this way you can also use generator expressions in the script.

Comment: Ah, right, should have thought of that... it's super-convoluted though :-P

Comment: Integrating this into a larger of script of mine, I'm having trouble preventing `generated.c` from being repeatedly generated.

Comment: ... and I've now asked a follow-up.